# Can we set List-Style-Position in pdf using iText 7 ? is there any API available?

Tags: itext7

Am trying to find an equivalent method in Itext 7 to set the below style on lists. Is there any API available in Itext7 ?

list-style-position: inside;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is API available to set analogue of `list-style-position` CSS property directly in `layout` code. For that, use `listElement.setProperty(Property.LIST_SYMBOL_POSITION, ListSymbolPosition.INSIDE);`

Example code:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

List defaultList = new List();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    defaultList
            .add("Am trying to find an equivalent method in Itext 7 to set the below style on lists. Is there any API available in Itext7");
}

List bulletPositionInsideList = new List();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    bulletPositionInsideList
            .add("Am trying to find an equivalent method in Itext 7 to set the below style on lists. Is there any API available in Itext7");
}
bulletPositionInsideList.setProperty(Property.LIST_SYMBOL_POSITION, ListSymbolPosition.INSIDE);

document.add(defaultList);
document.add(bulletPositionInsideList);
```

Visual result of default list vs one with list symbol position set to inside:

[image: visual result]

Comment: @Alexy In the case of the nested list can we sent a different property for parent and child?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347365/does-itext-7-supports-list-style-position-in-case-of-nested-lists